# Does every ruby on rails app need to be written on the console terminal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I don't like using the console terminal. Is it possible to use a text editor like bracket *(MY FAVORITE) to write ruby code? I've seen ruby files. Are those written on an editor? Or is it the case that all these schools teach you the basics through the console and later you can write code on an editor?

Comment: Yes obviously you can use text editors. You can write code in editor save it as 'file_name.rb' and run from console as 'ruby file_name.rb'

Comment: Did you bother *trying* to open the files in "MY FAVORITE" editor? You could have figured this out yourself if you had spent any time at all thinking about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby do not have to be written in the terminal.

I myself do most of my coding in [sublime](http://www.sublimetext.com/) and do run some commands in the terminal to run tests and generate some files. (Rails generators are quite awesome by the way)

I have a colleague who uses [Ruby mine](https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/) and from what I understand you can use that to do rails development without using the console.

Answer (score 0):

Yes obviously you can use text editors. 
You can write code in editor save it as `file_name.rb` and run from console as `ruby file_name.rb`

And this is just a start with `Ruby`. Just give your 20 minutes and you will get to know

https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart/

When you will get familiar with all the great things about `ruby`

You can start with `Rails`, as it's name suggests it actually get you started

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Just go on and you get fell in love with `Ruby on Rails` what it is called.

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot convenient to use text editors and write codes instead of giving yourself a hard time coding using the console.

[Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/)  is one of the widely used editors, very easy to use and free. I've always used this.

You could also check out some of the best editors here [5 Best editors - Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/five-best-text-editors-1564907215)

You can use any text editor and save the codes with the .rb extension `<file-name>.rb` and run it through terminal like this: `ruby filename.rb`